# Codeigniter query doesn't run even though it runs on the server

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, bluehost

I have a query made by codeigniter's query builder.

Up until recently, the query was working fine. 
Now, it gives us a blank page but I've made no changes to it.
I turned error reporting on and it gave the generic query of it didn't return any results

```
Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /application/models/order_model.php on line 311
```

I dumped the query and tried to run on the server itself, it works.

Is there anything else I can try to debug it?

Comment: If I drop and reupload the orders table in the database, the query works again. I still want to figure out why this happens in the first place though.

Comment: Yuo can start by posting (add full fragment of) `order_model.php` in your question body :-)